# is there something like microsoft sync framework in java?

Tags: java, swing, servlets, microsoft-sync-framework, data-synchronization

I am building an centralized inventory system using java(swing and servlets). I have local data stored in desktop application which needs to be in sync with an server.

Requirement is:-
1) When local stores are online ,data must be synchronized with server in real time.
2) Local store will have access to their data even if they go offline, but when they go online    all local changes must be reflected on server.

I got across microsoft sync framework which is exactly what I need. Is there something equivalent in java?

Comment: Short answer, no. There is nothing equivalent in Java. However, if your Java application runs on Windows servers then they can use it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Long answer yes :) See my answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill That's a Java file replication system. Not a built-in framework. But perhaps it meets OP's needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of [Open Source Replication and Synchronization Tools Written in Java](http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/java-open-source-replication-synchronization/view):

Of those listed the following might handle your "offline" requirement:

> [SymmetricDS](http://symmetricds.org/) – SymmetricDS is a web based, database independent, data synchronization system. Beyond replicating tables between relational databases the software incorporates functionality to handle a large number of databases, manage low-bandwidth connections and **work within periods of network outage**. The system supports two way replication, guaranteed delivery and multiple active schemas.

I'm sure the others are worth a quick look as well.

See also [Strategy for Offline/Online data synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271610/strategy-for-offline-online-data-synchronization) for some great discussion on things to think about/watch out for.

Comment: Thank goodness somebody provided an answer to this useful question before it was closed as "off topic."

Comment: hey the link is no longer there and i have the same question can you please tell me another way to access -> Open Source Replication and Synchronization Tools Written in Java:

Comment: @sitwaheed9 Well you could try the wayback machine. I've done that for you https://web.archive.org/web/20170527070954/http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/java-open-source-replication-synchronization/view